# Code for, returning True if the sum of 3 numbers from a list equals to x?

Tags: python

so I am trying to code def subsetSum(,) where it returns True if the sum of 3 numbers from a given list equals to x, which is a given number? The outcome is supposed to be like this:

```
>>> subsetSum([5, 4, 10, 20, 15, 19], 38)
True
>>> subsetSum([5, 4, 10, 20, 15, 19], 10)
False
```

So I tried coding like this but it only gives out False. I guess it only reads the first 3 numbers not the entire list. Don't know what I did wrong. Pls help? I am a beginner.:)

```py
def subsetSum(lst, x):
    for num1 in lst:
        for num2 in lst:
            for num3 in lst:
                if num1+num2+num3 == x:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
print(subsetSum([1,2,3,4,5], 6))
```

Comment: "_I guess it only reads the first 3 numbers not the entire list._" That's because of the `return` in the `else`. If the first 3 numbers don't match the target you return false and the function ends.

Comment: @takendarkk Actually, if the first element * 3 doesn't match the target, he returns False.

Answer (score 2):

You should only return `False` if you finished run on all your lists, as this:

```py
def subsetSum(lst, x):
    for num1 in lst:
        for num2 in lst:
            for num3 in lst:
                if num1+num2+num3 == x:
                    return True
    return False
print(subsetSum([1,2,3,4,5], 6)) # True
```

Just so you know, there is much faster solutions out there for this problem, like sorting the list can help you, and hashing it, take a look at [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/) for more eplanation about this problem

Comment: The first time the `if` statement executes, you are adding up the first element of the list three times. This cannot be what is intended.

Comment: hey! i understand this code the most. it works perfect! but I don't understand why the return False is below the first "for"?

Comment: @rosy How can this be the accepted answer? `print(subsetSum([5, 4, 10, 20, 15, 19], 15))` returns `True` because it adds 5 three times. Is this what the OP really wants?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, what @Reznik said, "You should only return False if you finished run on all your lists" is true. But you also have the additional problem that you are adding up the same elements. For example, the very first time the statment:

`if num1+num2+num3 == x:`

is executed, `num1`, `num2` and `num3` are all the first element of the passed in list.

```
from itertools import combinations

def subsetSum(lst, x):
    for c in combinations(lst, 3):
        if sum(c) == x:
            return True
    return False


print(subsetSum([5, 4, 10, 20, 15, 19], 38))
print(subsetSum([5, 4, 10, 20, 15, 19], 10))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks! I just knew about the combinations functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you return in the first iteration of your for loops, although if you wanted a shorter answer, you can use itertools combinations

```
from itertools import combinations
def subsetSum(lst, x):
    return any(sum(y) == x for y in combinations(lst, 3))
```

Comment: do permutations also give lists with duplicate elements?

Comment: @Ramesh - In the op's first example, yes it would return both `(19,15,4)` and `(19,4,15)` but it short circuits if any are true

Comment: Yeah, just asking if it gives `(19,19,19)` or `(19,4,4)`...or is that what combinations would do?

Comment: @Ramesh - https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: @Ramesh - Looking into it more, combinations would be more appropriate here - (The code for combinations() can be also expressed as a subsequence of permutations() after filtering entries where the elements are not in sorted order (according to their position in the input pool))

Answer (score 0):

you can just iterate through the length of the list checking if the 3 digits add up to the sum.

```py
def subsetSum(lst, x):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 3):
        if sum(lst[i:i+3]) == x:
            return True
    return False


print(subsetSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6))
```

Comment: I think the op would expect `subsetSum([1,2,3,4], 8)` to return true

Comment: Ah ok yeah i see what you mean, i was thinking 3 consecutive numbers, rather than any 3 numbers.